# Antlr4: Prevent rule and token conflicts

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

Given following grammar:

```
grammar minimal;

rule: '(' rule_name body ')';
rule_name : NAME;
body : '(' AT NAME ')';

AT : 'at';
NAME: LETTER ANY_CHAR*;
fragment LETTER: 'a' .. 'z' | 'A' .. 'Z';
fragment ANY_CHAR: LETTER | '0' .. '9' | '-' | '_';
WHITESPACE: ( ' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n' )+ -> skip;
```

How can I match (at (at bar)) with at as a valid function name without getting conflicts with the AT token from body without rearranging the grammar?

Comment: Are you asking for something other than `rule: '(' (NAME | AT) ')'`, or is that allowed?

Comment: yes, originally the AT token is matched by other rules somehow deep nested but in the rule part it should be possible to write at matching the name as valid

Comment: I think `NAME | at` is what you want, then. If there's something in your requirements that prohibits that, then I'm not sure what it is. You may want to clarify your question.

Comment: changed in example to clarify my question

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I think again, you can just do `rule_name: NAME | AT`, right? Or does that break something else?

Comment: I think i can do it but would prefer to match at as a NAME not as an AT token :/

Comment: FYI what you're attempting is commonly referred to as *non-reserved keyword*.

Answer (score 2):

To remove the conflict and preserve the intended token type:

```
rule_name : ( NAME | AT ) -> type(NAME) ;
```